# How to pass array value into PHP Recursive function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created dynamic menu using `PHP Recursive function` it is working fine.
Now i am implementing specific menu items for specific user. For this i have added one more field in login table and i stored data like this in that field `1,3,4,6,7,8,9,10`. But my problem is if give the data static it is working fine but if i pass menu items variable into query, it is showing only the first item and giving implode invalid argument passed warning.

Why i am getting this message? please help me. thanks in advance

```
//getting login table values
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from login");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
//storing values to array
$menuitems=explode(',',$row['field3']);
//print_r($menuitems);
//exit(0);

function submenu($parentid=0){
    global $con;
    global $menuitems;
    //converting array into string
    $menuitems=implode(',',$menuitems);
    //passing the menuitems into sqlquery if i pass data like this i am 
    //getting A menu items and getting waning message
    $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test WHERE refid=".$parentid. "AND 
    id IN ('$menuitems')");
    {
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if($rowcount>0){
            echo '<ul>';
        }
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            if($row['refid']==0){
                echo '<li class="limain">'.$row['name'];
                submenu($row['id']);
                echo '</li>';
            } else {
                if($row['userdefined']){
                    echo '<li class="lichild"><a href="'.$row['userdefined'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li class="lichild">'.$row['name'];
                }
                submenu($row['id']);
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        if($rowcount>0){
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
}
//executing function
submenu();
?>
```

Comment: I find those stray curly braces odd. It probably does not do anything right now but can lead to some unexpected behavior with `const` and `use` and `namespace` fyi

Comment: this line : `$menuitems=implode(',',$menuitems);`  re-assign global $menuitems , mean u can not use implode 2 time on it as your recursive do. Use another name for your $menuitems as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to hold back my actual thoughts on your coding logic and style and simply recommend that you remove `$menuitems=implode(',',$menuitems);` and change `$menuitems=explode(',',$row['field3']);` into just `$menuitems=$row['field3'];`

Additionally, remove the single-quotes from `'$menuitems'` within your SQL.